# railo application.cfc this.mappings not working

Tags: coldfusion, components, railo, mappings, application.cfc

i am using the latest version of railo, and am trying to get the per-application mappings to work.  this is what i am doing:

```
<cfcomponent name="MyApp">
    <cfset THIS.Name = "MyApp">
    <cfset THIS.Mappings["/myapp"] = ExpandPath(".")>
</cfcomponent>
```

so, i am trying to be able to access components within this application folder through a myapp.* mappings rather than having to to rootapp.myapp.*  (from what i understand, this component setup should then work.

however, my components cannot be accessed by this mapping, and when i do a cfdump on the application variable in my code, it will show that the "applicationname" is set to "MyApp", but nothing shows for the mappings.

does railo not support these mappings, or am i doing something wrong?

EDIT:

this is the exact error that i am getting:

```
invalid component definition, can't find myapp.data.MyObject
```

the `myapp` mapping should have been made, and the `MyObject` does exist.  here is my structure:

```
/rootfolder/myapp/Application.cfc
/rootfolder/myapp/data/MyObject.cfc
/rootfolder/myapp/pages/MyPage.cfm
```

in short, "MyPage.cfm" relies on the mapping to easily access the "MyObject" component.  the Application.cfc *should* be loaded as the cfml processor should start moving up directories until it finds one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is OK, I've just did the same for application deep in directories tree and it works fine.

> however, my components cannot be accessed by this mapping,

What is exact error? "invalid component definition, can't find myapp.xyz"?

Are your cfm and cfc in the same directory? (this is basically what you are trying to do)

> and when i do a cfdump on the application variable in my code, it will show that the "applicationname" is set to "MyApp", but nothing shows for the mappings.

You wont see this info by dumping the application scope. Only option is to use Application.cfc as usual cfc.

```
<cfset app = CreateObject("component",  "application") />
<cfdump var="#app#">
```

EDIT. You have two solutions here.

Define mapping like this, so path will be calculated for Application.cfc:

```
<cfset this.mappings["/myapp2"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())>
```

Or change component path like this:

```
<cfset MyObject = CreateObject("component",  "myapp.data.MyObject") />
```

Problem is in differences between paths returned by `ExpandPath` and `getCurrentTemplatePath()`.

Comment: works like a charm, and best of all, it makes sense.  thanks!

Comment: oh, and by the way, i used the getDirectoryFromPath(...) solution; i am trying to make this application fluid and not tied to any hard-coded paths, so the other solution would not be ideal.

Comment: simply dumping this.mappings and then aborting in Application.cfc is always the best way to troubleshoot the calculated mapping path to make sure it points where you think it does. `writeDump(this.mappings); abort;`

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As Sergii pointed out, the syntax is valid, but the net effect is the same.

Try using this syntax

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset THIS.Name = "MyApp">
    <cfset THIS.mappings = { "/myapp" = ExpandPath(".") } >
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: This syntax does absolutely the same.